# json cleanup and remove bad columns and unnecessary lists

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following `json`:

```
{
    "pfe-statistics" : [
    {
        "pfe-traffic-statistics" : [
        {
            "pfe-input-packets" : [
            {
                "data" : "3895887"
            }
            ], 
            "input-pps" : [
            {
                "data" : "0"
            }
            ], 
            "pfe-output-packets" : [
            {
                "data" : "1114541"
            }
            ], 
            "output-pps" : [
            {
                "data" : "0"
            }
            ]
        }
        ], 
        "pfe-local-traffic-statistics" : [
        {
            "pfe-input-packets" : [
            {
                "data" : "3893502"
            }
            ], 
            "pfe-output-packets" : [
            {
                "data" : "1114541"
            }
            ], 
            "software-input-control-drops" : [
            {
                "data" : "0"
            }
            ], 
            "software-input-high-drops" : [
            {
                "data" : "0"
            }
            ], 
            "software-input-medium-drops" : [
            {
                "data" : "0"
            }
            ], 
            "software-input-low-drops" : [
            {
                "data" : "0"
            }
            ], 
            "software-output-low-drops" : [
            {
                "data" : "0"
            }
            ], 
            "hardware-input-drops" : [
            {
                "data" : "0"
            }
            ]
        }
        ], 
        "pfe-local-protocol-statistics" : [
        {
            "hdlc-keepalive-count" : [
            {
                "data" : "0"
            }
            ], 
            "atm-oam-count" : [
            {
                "data" : "0"
            }
            ], 
            "fr-lmi-count" : [
            {
                "data" : "0"
            }
            ], 
            "ppp-lcp-ncp-count" : [
            {
                "data" : "0"
            }
            ], 
            "ospf-hello-count" : [
            {
                "data" : "0"
            }
            ], 
            "ospf3-hello-count" : [
            {
                "data" : "0"
            }
            ], 
            "rsvp-hello-count" : [
            {
                "data" : "0"
            }
            ], 
            "ldp-hello-count" : [
            {
                "data" : "0"
            }
            ], 
            "bfd-count" : [
            {
                "data" : "0"
            }
            ], 
            "isis-iih-count" : [
            {
                "data" : "0"
            }
            ], 
            "lacp-count" : [
            {
                "data" : "0"
            }
            ], 
            "arp-count" : [
            {
                "data" : "0"
            }
            ], 
            "ether-oam-count" : [
            {
                "data" : "0"
            }
            ], 
            "unknown-count" : [
            {
                "data" : "0"
            }
            ]
        }
        ], 
        "pfe-hardware-discard-statistics" : [
        {
            "timeout-discard" : [
            {
                "data" : "0"
            }
            ], 
            "truncated-key-discard" : [
            {
                "data" : "0"
            }
            ], 
            "bits-to-test-discard" : [
            {
                "data" : "0"
            }
            ], 
            "data-error-discard" : [
            {
                "data" : "0"
            }
            ], 
            "stack-underflow-discard" : [
            {
                "data" : "0"
            }
            ], 
            "stack-overflow-discard" : [
            {
                "data" : "0"
            }
            ], 
            "bad-route-discard" : [
            {
                "data" : "0"
            }
            ], 
            "nexthop-discard" : [
            {
                "data" : "0"
            }
            ], 
            "invalid-iif-discard" : [
            {
                "data" : "0"
            }
            ], 
            "info-cell-discard" : [
            {
                "data" : "0"
            }
            ], 
            "fabric-discard" : [
            {
                "data" : "0"
            }
            ]
        }
        ], 
        "pfe-chip-statistics" : [
        {
            "input-checksum" : [
            {
                "data" : "0"
            }
            ], 
            "output-mtu" : [
            {
                "data" : "0"
            }
            ]
        }
        ]
    }
    ]
}
```

I want to generate the following:

```
{
    "pfe-statistics" :
    {
        "pfe-traffic-statistics" :
        {
            "pfe-input-packets" : "56601136", 
            "input-pps" : "30", 
            "pfe-output-packets" : "71427636", 
            "output-pps" : "28", 
            "pfe-fabric-input" : "0", 
            "pfe-fabric-input-pps" : "0", 
            "pfe-fabric-output" : "0", 
            "pfe-fabric-output-pps" : "0"
        }, 
        "pfe-local-traffic-statistics" :
        {
            "pfe-input-packets" : "56226309", 
            "pfe-output-packets" : "142458974", 
            "software-input-control-drops" : "0", 
            "software-input-high-drops" : "0", 
            "software-input-medium-drops" : "0", 
            "software-input-low-drops" : "0", 
            "software-output-low-drops" : "0", 
            "hardware-input-drops" : "0"
        }, 
        "pfe-local-protocol-statistics" :
        {
            "hdlc-keepalive-count" : "0", 
            "atm-oam-count" : "0", 
            "fr-lmi-count" : "0", 
            "ppp-lcp-ncp-count" : "0", 
            "ospf-hello-count" : "0", 
            "ospf3-hello-count" : "0", 
            "rsvp-hello-count" : "0", 
            "ldp-hello-count" : "0", 
            "bfd-count" : "49316136", 
            "isis-iih-count" : "0", 
            "lacp-count" : "0", 
            "arp-count" : "433208", 
            "ether-oam-count" : "0", 
            "unknown-count" : "0"
        }, 
        "pfe-hardware-discard-statistics" :
        {
            "timeout-discard" : "0", 
            "truncated-key-discard" : "0", 
            "bits-to-test-discard" : "0", 
            "data-error-discard" : "0", 
            "tcp-header-error-discard" : "0", 
            "stack-underflow-discard" : "0", 
            "stack-overflow-discard" : "0", 
            "bad-route-discard" : "0", 
            "nexthop-discard" : "0", 
            "invalid-iif-discard" : "0", 
            "info-cell-discard" : "0", 
            "fabric-discard" : "0"
        }, 
        "pfe-chip-statistics" :
        {
            "input-checksum" : "0", 
            "output-mtu" : "0"
        }
    }
}
```

I wrote the following function but can't make get it to work 100 percent:

```
d = {}
l = []
def compact_json(df):
    for k, v in df.items():
        if isinstance(v, list):
            print("list")
            print(k)
            if "data" not in v[0].keys():
                val = v[0].keys()
                if val not in l:
                    l.append(k)
            compact_json(v[0])

            #d.update(k)
        if isinstance(v[0], dict):
            print("dict")
            if "data" in v[0].keys():
                print("if data yes")
                print(k, v[0]["data"])
                d1 = {k: v}
                #d[val] = v[0]["data"]
                d[k] = v[0]["data"]
            else:
                print("else no data")
                print(v[0])
                compact_json(v[0])

compact_json(df)
print("==============")
print(d)
```

I can only print leaves but not the branches. Note that I want to make it universal for multiple `json`, so nested depths can be different in all the forms.

Comment: Unrelated, but once you've unserialized your json string, it's not json anymore, just a plain python object - so the fact it comes from a json string is totally irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a nested dictionary comprehension:

```
result = {a:{j:{l:b['data'] for y in k for l, [b] in y.items()} 
             for g in c for j, k in g.items()} for a, c in data.items()}
```

---

```
import json
print(json.dumps(result, indent=4))
```

Output:

```
{
  "pfe-statistics": {
     "pfe-traffic-statistics": {
        "pfe-input-packets": "3895887",
        "input-pps": "0",
        "pfe-output-packets": "1114541",
        "output-pps": "0"
    },
    "pfe-local-traffic-statistics": {
        "pfe-input-packets": "3893502",
        "pfe-output-packets": "1114541",
        "software-input-control-drops": "0",
        "software-input-high-drops": "0",
        "software-input-medium-drops": "0",
        "software-input-low-drops": "0",
        "software-output-low-drops": "0",
        "hardware-input-drops": "0"
    },
    "pfe-local-protocol-statistics": {
        "hdlc-keepalive-count": "0",
        "atm-oam-count": "0",
        "fr-lmi-count": "0",
        "ppp-lcp-ncp-count": "0",
        "ospf-hello-count": "0",
        "ospf3-hello-count": "0",
        "rsvp-hello-count": "0",
        "ldp-hello-count": "0",
        "bfd-count": "0",
        "isis-iih-count": "0",
        "lacp-count": "0",
        "arp-count": "0",
        "ether-oam-count": "0",
        "unknown-count": "0"
    },
    "pfe-hardware-discard-statistics": {
        "timeout-discard": "0",
        "truncated-key-discard": "0",
        "bits-to-test-discard": "0",
        "data-error-discard": "0",
        "stack-underflow-discard": "0",
        "stack-overflow-discard": "0",
        "bad-route-discard": "0",
        "nexthop-discard": "0",
        "invalid-iif-discard": "0",
        "info-cell-discard": "0",
        "fabric-discard": "0"
    },
    "pfe-chip-statistics": {
        "input-checksum": "0",
        "output-mtu": "0"
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: the downvote might be due to a miss click i am sorry for that,

Comment: what is i have to apply this to multiple jsons with different depths and different depth on different level in the same json?